# Como efetuar TDD na camada Service

Tags: hibernate, mvc, tdd, junit, mockito

Participo de um projeto que utiliza camadas MVC com framework Hibernate persistindo em um Postgres. Para testes utiliza-se o Junit e para mock o Mockito (ainda não tenho conhecimento e prática sobre o mesmo)

Então queria saber, como vocês trabalham o TDD com a camada service, por exemplo como você validam Hibernate Annotations.

O que você fazem e qual a experiência que podem compartilhar?

Comment: Caso outras pessoas queiram contribuir com este post sinta-se a vontade até para disseminar o conhecimento!

Answer (score 21):

## TDD ou Teste Unitário?

Existe uma grande diferença entre TDD e Teste Unitário. O TDD tem como base testes unitários, mas ambos conceitos não são exatamente sinônimos.

**TDD** (*Test Driven Development*) é uma metodologia de desenvolvimento que mede o progresso do projeto de acordo com os resultados dos testes.

**Teste Unitário** é um dos tipos de teste que se costuma fazer em software. Existem ainda testes de integração, de sistema, de usuário, de carga, de desempenho e outros.

Um teste unitário deveria testar um único cenário de um método do sistema sem depender de recursos externos, como bancos de dados, configurações e outros fatores que possam interferir no resultado. Em resumo, o teste unitário deve testar somente uma coisa.

## TDD na prática

O TDD funciona bem para alguns tipos de projetos, principalmente quando os requisitos estão bem definidos e é possível escrever cada o teste antes da implementação. É o caso ideal.

Na prática, entretanto, muitos dos requisitos vão evoluindo no decorrer do projeto, tanto por mudanças nos negócios, quanto por falha na elicitação e mesmo pela maturação do entendimento dos usuários. Este e outros motivos inviabilizam um TDD "puro" porque ele acrescenta um *overhead* de esforço muito grande e muitas equipes não podem se dar a esse luxo.

Outro fator que atrapalha é a maturidade da equipe. Não adianta ensinar um junior a usar JUnit e achar que ele vai conseguir fazer TDD. Não é fácil criar um sistema testável, que é uma das qualidades de uma boa arquitetura do software.

O importante é entender que TDD não é uma [bala de prata](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bala_de_prata) .

## Testes unitários na prática

### Teste as funcionalidades importantes

O que tenho visto no mercado e que tem dado certo é focar o teste naquilo que é importante. Não há tempo de testar tudo, então o foco deve ser nas funcionalidades centrais do sistema e não em cadastros (CRUD).

Muitas pessoas tem dúvidas sobre o que testar, algumas sugerem até testar rotinas do framework ou, no caso de Java, verificar se o Hibernate está salvando os dados no banco. Isso deixa o desenvolvedor louco e vai na direção errada, pois no final ele vai testar coisas que deveriam estar funcionando e deixar de lado as mais importantes.

### Teste unitário, mas não tão unitário

O teste não precisa ser exatamente unitário, no sentido de testar apenas um método.

Trabalhei num projeto que envolve integração com mais de meia dúzia de sistemas. São integrações para todos os gostos: Web Services, arquivos, bancos de dados. Muitos dos sistemas ainda estão em processo de mudança. Seria inviável criar *mocks* para tudo e ter que atualizar os *mocks* cada vez que um sistema mudasse.

Então, para citar um exemplo de teste de importação de arquivo, eu criei um método JUnit que executa a tarefa (*job*) de importação e verifica se o registro foi armazenado com sucesso. Embora acabe testando muita coisa de uma vez só, isso está sendo suficiente para garantir a funcionalidade.

Não é "pecado" acessar o banco de dados em teste unitário. O ruim é ter o teste falhando frequentemente caso as tabelas não estejam no estado necessário para a correta execução. Mas nada impede de inicializar valores no *setup* do teste. Ou ainda há a opção de usar um framework como [TestNG](http://testng.org/), onde você pode definir a ordem de execução. Na verdade, não é exatamente a ordem, o que você pode definir é que um método de teste X depende do teste Y ter executado antes. Particularmente gosto muito do TestNG.

### O *design* conta muito

Falando especificamente sobre sua camada de serviços, posso repassar as lições que a experiência me trouxe.

O mais importante é sempre projetar suas classes e métodos para que sejam testáveis. No começo é difícil e você deve gastar um tempo com *refactoring*. Faça com que cada método ou rotina importante seja o menos acoplado possível com outras rotinas e configurações estáticas. Abuse da Inversão de Controle.

Acompanhe um exemplo que darei no próximo tópico

## Um exemplo fictício

Vamos criar um classe responsável pela importação de um arquivo. Suponha que a primeira implementação seja bem ingênua:

```java
public class ImportadorArquivo {
    public void importar() {

        //carrega local da configuração
        File arquivo = new File(Configuracao.LOCAL_ARQUIVO);

        //lista com itens lidos do arquivo
        List<Entidade> entidadesLidas = new ArrayList<>();

        //vários comandos para ler e interpretar o arquivo, colocando itens na lista...
        String[] linhas = FileUtil.lerLinhas(arquivo);
        for (String linha : linhas) {
            Entidade e = new Entidade();
            //preenche entidade com os dados da linha...
            entidadesLidas.add(e);
        }

        //grava itens no banco
        for (Entidade e : entidadesLidas) {
            JPAUtil.getEntityManager().persist(e);
        }

    }
}
```

É um método bem ruim de testar, certo? Vamos refatorar essa classe para deixá-la mais testável:

```java
public class ImportadorArquivo {

    private File arquivo;
    private EntityManager em;

    //recebe arquivo em entity manager (IoC)
    public ImportadorArquivo(File arquivo, EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
        this.arquivo = arquivo;
    }

    public void importar() {
        List<Entidade> entidadesLidas = ler();
        salvar(entidadesLidas);
    }

    public List<Entidade> ler() {
        List<Entidade> entidadesLidas = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] linhas = FileUtil.lerLinhas(arquivo);
        for (String linha : linhas) {
            entidadesLidas.add(interpretar(linha));
        }
        return entidadesLidas;
    }

    public Entidade interpretar(String linhaArquivo) {
        Entidade e = new Entidade();
        //preenche entidade com os dados da linha...
        return e;
    }

    public void salvar(List<Entidade> entidadesLidas) {
        for (Entidade e : entidadesLidas) {
            em.persist(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Note que agora cada método possui uma ação bem definida e distinta. Isso permite testar cada ação individualmente.

Perceba também que a classe recebe as configurações por parâmetro. Isso é um tipo de Inversão de Controle. Isso permite você testar a classe sem precisar de framework ou mágica alguma.

**Imagine o potencial de um bom *design* se aplicado a todo o sistema?**

## Exemplos reais

Tenho trabalhado em algumas pequenas bibliotecas e frameworks usando TDD, pelo menos até certo ponto.

Vou listar aqui dois projetos recentes e atualizados no GitHub com aproximadamente 90% de cobertura de testes unitários:

- [MyQ](https://github.com/utluiz/myq): uma biblioteca para organizar, carregar e processar queries SQL em um projeto Java.
- [T-Rex](https://github.com/utluiz/t-rex): um gerador de planilhas Excel através de *templates* e uma expression language.

Embora eu saiba que ainda tenho muito a aprender e melhorar em minhas implementações, sugiro que é um bom exercício olhar o design das classes nesses projetos e como eles permitem que os testes unitários sejam executados sem nenhum framework de *mock*.

## Leitura adicional

Para uma discussão interessante sobre o assunto, veja meu artigo [*O TDD está morto?*](http://luizricardo.org/2014/05/o-tdd-esta-morto/) e, se entender Inglês, assista o vídeo *[Is TDD Dead?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9quxZsLcfo)*.

Comment: Mas por exemplo no meu caso, utiliza-se validações pelas anotattions no model. Como faria para validar?

Comment: @Macario1983 Não é preciso testar a validação do model, você precisa apenas verificar se as anotações estão corretas, já que o Hibernate vai validar pra vc. No entanto, caso queira fazê-lo, você pode forçar uma validação manual com a `ValidatorFactory`. Veja um exemplo [aqui](http://aredko.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/force-your-beans-validation-using-jsr.html).

Comment: Convém validar se tal campo recebeu tal anotação? Se sim, qual forma seria boa?

Comment: @Macario1983 Para mim não faz muito sentido validar isso. Mas se quiser mesmo fazê-lo, basta usar um pouco de reflexão. Exemplo: `Assert.assertNotNull( MinhaEntidade.getClass().getAnnotation(Anotacao.class));`. Isso verifica a anotação `Anotacao` para uma classe. Fazer com métodos é algo semelhante. Pesquisei um pouco sobre anotações ou coloque mais uma pergunta específica sobre isso, pois é um assunto um pouco extenso.

Comment: Li seu texto e artigo e obrigado, pelas ideias, vou ver seu código de texto, eu também já brinquei com o TestNG e gostei muito mas como sou novato no desenvolvimento estou buscando inspirações e referencias para desenvolver.

Answer (score 0):

Você mencionou testes na camada Service mas mencionou, como exemplo, testes com Hibernate Annotations.

De antemão digo que não consigo imaginar o uso de Hibernate Annotations na camada Service, a não ser que seu teste unitário esteja **transpassando** o código do próprio Service e alcançando o código da entidade e, por consequência, as entidades e as salvando em algum banco. Neste caso, não seria um teste unitário, mas um [teste de integração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/360640/4492).

Posto isto, vou usar um exemplo de um Service mais clássico. Como estamos falando de TDD, não vamos começar pelo Service mas sim pelo teste do mesmo. Será o teste que irá guiar a nossa implementação.

Mas antes, precisamos definir o requisito no qual este service vai atender.

## Exemplo: Cadastro de pessoa

Como exemplo, digamos que você precisa inserir uma pessoa no banco de dados, validando se o nome dela está correto (é diferente de nulo) e se ela já existe no banco de dados. Se já existir, deve retornar erro.

Vamos criar então o `PessoaServiceTest` com os seguintes métodos de teste:

- `naoInserirPessoaSeNomeInvalido`
- `naoInserirPessoaSePessoaExiste`
- `inserirPessoaComSucesso`

Que são os nossos casos de teste. Seria possível pensar em mais, mas para efeito de exemplo, vamos nos ater a estes acima.

Como pode observar, os métodos tem nomes bem claros, explicando o que estão testando.

Em nosso `PessoaServiceTest`, vamos criar o método `naoInserirPessoaSeNomeInvalido`. Esperamos, neste caso, algum tipo de exception, tal como `NomePessoaInvalidoException`:

```
@Test(expect = NomePessoaInvalidoException.class)
public void naoInserirPessoaSeNomeInvalido() {

    PessoaService pessoaService = new PessoaService();
    pessoaService.inserir(new Pessoa(null));

}
```

Ao criar este teste, imaginando que você está começando praticamente do zero, você vai se deparar com vários erros:

- classe de PessoaService não existe
- método inserir no PessoaService não existe
- classe Pessoa não existe
- construtor da classe pessoa não existe para receber o nome
- NomePessoaInvalidoException não existe

Neste momento, você precisa resolver todas estas pendências para não ter erros de compilação. A ideia agora é só resolver estes problemas de compilação, sem implementação da lógica (ainda).

Feito isto, você vai conseguir rodar o teste. O erro vai dar um erro, pois a exception `NomePessoaInvalidoException` não foi retornada.

Assim, começa a implementação. Você vai precisar ler o nome da pessoa (criando o atributo nome dentro da pessoa) e verificar se está válido (não nulo):

```
@Service
class PessoaService {

    public Pessoa inserir(Pessoa pessoa) {

        if (pessoa.getNome() == null) {
            throw new NomePessoaInvalidoException("Nome está nulo");
        }

    }
}
```

Após isto, o teste vai passar. Os demais casos são similares, a principal diferença é se precisar buscar uma pessoa, você vai precisar mockar a chamada que faz a busca no banco de dados.

No caso do `naoInserirPessoaSePessoaExiste`, você teria um teste mockando o PessoaRepository para te retornar uma pessoa. O código do teste ficaria assim:

```
@Test(expect = PessoaJaExisteException.class)
public void naoInserirPessoaSePessoaExiste() {

    PessoaRepository pessoaRepository = mock(PessoaRepository.class);
    PessoaService pessoaService = new PessoaService(pessoaRepository);
    pessoaService.inserir(new Pessoa("Eduardo"));

}
```

Ao rodar daria erro. Para funcionar, o `PessoaService` ficaria algo como:

```
public Pessoa inserir(Pessoa pessoa) {

    if (pessoa.getNome() == null) {
        throw new NomePessoaInvalidoException("Nome está nulo");
    }

    if (this.pessoaRepository.countByName("Eduardo").isPresent()) {
        throw new PessoaJaExisteException("Eduardo já existe");
    }

}
```

O caso de sucesso segue a mesma lógica. Você poderia fazer um `assertNotNull` para o retorno do método `inserir`, implementando depois no Service a chamada para o método `save` do repositório. Espero que tenha ficado claro.