# Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?

Tags: testes, engenharia-de-software, testes-de-unidade, tdd, testes-funcionais

Na pergunta do meta [5 tags diferentes para "testes"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1376/101) eu notei que tenho alguma dificuldade para entender todos estes termos sobre testes.

Certamente testes passaram ser muito importantes ao longo da trajetória do desenvolvimento de software. Com isto proliferam conceitos e a sopa de letrinhas está cada vez maior.

O que diferencia os conceitos envolvidos em testes? As siglas e as definições formais são fáceis de descobrir.

Teste de software, testes unitários ([sei que este é errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/567879/101)) ou testes de unidade (há diferença?), testes funcionais, TDD, *quality assurance*, *acceptance testing*. Existe algum outro termo relacionado que seja muito importante para ser destacado?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## Teste de Software

Usando os termos da [Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_software):

> É a investigação do software a fim de fornecer informações sobre sua qualidade em relação ao contexto em que ele deve operar. Isso inclui o processo de utilizar o produto para encontrar seus defeitos.

***Teste*** é o termo mais geral para ver se um determinado software funciona. Pode ser um produto inteiro, parte dele, um método, etc.

O teste pode ser realizado pelo próprio desenvolvedor, por um testador especializado ou por um usuário do sistema. Isso pode ocorrer em qualquer fase do projeto, dependendo do modelo adotado (cascata, iterativo, evolutivo).

Na maioria dos projetos existe uma *fase de testes*, quando geralmente as funcionalidades da versão estão fechadas o foco maior da equipe é descobrir e corrigir defeitos ainda ocultos.

Os testes podem se dividir em diversos tipos e classificações.

### Quanto ao conhecimento sobre o software

- **Teste de caixa branca**: quando se avalia o funcionamento interno do software. Por exemplo, se determinados métodos executam corretamente.
- **Teste de caixa preta**: quando se avalia o comportamento do software, através de suas interfaces. Por exemplo, quando o usuário usa o sistema para ver se ele retorna valores esperados após um cálculo.

### Quanto à natureza do teste

Testes podem ser realizados em vários níveis e para diversos fins:

- **Teste Unitário**: testa partes específicas do sistema, como classes e métodos.
- **Teste de Integração**: testa vários componentes de um sistema funcionando de uma só vez.
- **Teste de Sistema** ou **Homologação** ou **SIT** (*System Integration Testing*): execução do sistema do ponto de vista do usuário, embora não realizado pelo usuário final.
- **Teste de Aceitação** ou **UAT** (*User Acceptance Testing*): teste realizado pelo usuário para verificar se o software está de acordo com o que foi contratado.
- **Teste de Regressão**: testes já realizados são executados novamente após modificações no software para garantir que não houve um efeito colateral inesperado.

### Testes não-funcionais

Além de verificar se as implementações de sistema estão corretas, determinados tipos de teste verificam aspectos não-funcionais do mesmo. Por exemplo:

- **Teste de Desempenho (Performance)**: verifica o desempenho do sistema com uma carga normal de usuários. Por exemplo, o tempo de resposta médio é de 2 segundos com até mil usuários.
- **Testes de Carga (Volume)**: verifica a capacidade máxima do sistema, ou seja, o ponto onde ele trava ou deixa de responder em tempo adequado.
- **Teste de Resiliência (*Stress*)**: verifica o comportamento do sistema e sua capacidade de se recuperar de falhas inesperadas, como queda de energia, falha em banco de dados, picos de acesso.

### Automação de testes

É possível realizar todos os tipos de teste sem automação. Por outro lado, há grande vantagem em automatizar alguns deles para a repetição sem esforço do mesmo.

Um Teste Unitário pode ser executado criando-se uma classe ou script independente para testar métodos e classes. Em Java, seria um método `main`.

Mas se usado num framework de automação, o mesmo Teste Unitário pode ser executado quantas vezes necessário. Seria um Teste de Regressão sem custo adicional. Em Java isso pode ser feito com JUnit.

## [*Test Driven Development*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Driven_Development) (TDD)

O TDD é uma metodologia de desenvolvimento baseada em testes. A ideia principal é inverter a sequência "tradicional" de desenvolvimento colocando o teste em primeiro lugar, antes da implementação.

Você escreve cada teste conforme o respectivo requisito. Então dá para acompanhar o progresso na medida em que cada teste deixa de falhar e obtém sucesso.

Muitas pessoas escrevem Testes Unitários e acham que estão fazendo TDD. Não é a mesma coisa. Ocorre que as equipes que adotam TDD geralmente se utilizam de Testes Unitários automatizados para agilizar o processo.

Tem um pouquinho mais de informações sobre testes e TDD [nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19028/227).

## [Garantia de Qualidade](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garantia_da_qualidade) ou *Quality Assurance* (QA)

QA não é diretamente relacionada a software. É uma área que tenta garantir a qualidade em todos os aspectos de um projeto ou serviço através de processos de auditorias.

Ela possui suas próprias técnicas, certificações e processos. Tudo isso é independente do ciclo de desenvolvimento de software.

Comment: Há uma confusão conceitual muito importante sobre TDD aqui e na outra resposta linkada. Elas sugerem que você precisa ter os requisitos, escrever os testes, e daí fazer os testes passarem - tudo no plural. TDD é exatamente o contrário: Você precisa ter 1 pequeníssimo requisito, escrever 1 teste e daí fazer o teste passar, então você refatora e escreve o próximo teste. TDD quer justamente permitir a evolução dos requisitos ao longo do projeto. Cada teste garante um pequeno requisito e a suíte de testes garante que nada foi quebrado. TDD dá a sensação do progresso mas não se propõe a medi-lo!

Comment: @Caffé Concordo em parte. Alterei as duas respostas para tirar o plural, porque a ideia original é realmente escrever cada teste individualmente, ou pelo menos ter a possibilidade de se fazer isso. Como o TDD foi baseado no XP, a ideia é evoluir a arquitetura do sistema aos poucos. Na prática isso raramente funciona pois numa equipe com desenvolvedores trabalhando em paralelo o resultado seria arquiteturas paralelas, código duplicado e um trabalho enorme fazendo merge. É melhor ter uma arquitetura inicial enxuta e pelo menos os testes dos requisitos mais críticos desde o início.

Comment: @Caffé Também concordo que TDD permite construir o sistema de forma incremental, mas dizer que TDD "permite a evolução dos requisitos ao longo do projeto" é exatamente o contrário do que o próprio autor do TDD diz (ver vídeo ao final da outra resposta). Se os requisitos "evoluem" no sentido de que se modificam ao longo do tempo (são instáveis), então a cada mudança os testes anteriores não representam mais o comportamento esperado do sistema, portanto TDD pode não ser adequado a menos que valha a pena ou seja possível o esforço de reescrever os testes inúmeras vezes.

Comment: Assisti o vídeo agora novamente (eu assisti esse hangout e os demais ao vivo naquela época). Realmente não consigo perceber onde o Kent Beck sugere que evolução dos requisitos não é suportada pelo TDD. Toda a filosofia (e ferramentas - inclusive XP e TDD) desenvolvida durante vários anos e formalizada depois no manifesto Ágil é **fundamentada** no fato de que requisitos mudam ao longo do projeto. **MUDANÇA** é o alicerce do Ágil e portanto a razão de ser das suas ferramentas como TDD. Inclusive, outra ferramenta Ágil é a Integração Contínua, onde o problema dos trabalhosos merges é resolvido.

Comment: Filosofia à parte, o que tenho visto na prática é o TDD, acompanhado de outras práticas, funcionando sim. É claro que é preciso primeiro aprender a fazer, e wikipedia e outros artigos equivocados na internet infelizmente não ajudam muito. E é claro também que TDD não é única coisa que funciona. Eu aprendo diariamente muita coisa com outros programadores que fazem um trabalho fantástico e rendem muita grana pra suas empresas e que nem sabem direito o que é TDD (apesar de que alguns pensam que sabem).

Comment: Em tempo, @utluiz, não estou tentando te passar nada novo. Para mim está claro que, embora nos expressemos de maneiras diferentes sobre estes conceitos, você os conhece bem. Minha intenção é apenas mostrar outro ponto de vista para quem mais passar por aqui - o ponto de vista de que TDD funciona e de que é útil justamente em projetos onde os requisitos mudam.

Comment: @Caffé Perfeito. Provavelmente não passei uma imagem completa e realista do que eu penso sobre TDD. Defendo a metodologia como um estilo de vida, não só como uma prática específica dentro de projetos de desenvolvimento. No entanto, minha resposta ressaltou a crítica que tenho em como o processo acaba sendo executado na prática. A verdade é que a maioria dos projetos que vejo começam bem, mas acaba abandonando o TDD quando ocorrem muitas mudanças ou em fases posteriores porque dá muito trabalho refatorar os testes na medida em que os requisitos mudam.

Comment: Claro que alguém poderia argumentar que isso é fruto de preguiça dos desenvolvedores, profissionais inexperientes, tempo insuficiente, arquitetura ruim, etc. Mas como a grande maioria das empresas sofre com esses problemas, então raramente o TDD em sua forma pura pode ser bem aplicado. Quanto ao vídeo, provavelmente fiz uma confusão. Acho que foi o David que falou alguma coisa sobre o TDD não ser viável para determinados tipos de projeto. Mas, embora tenha razão em um ou outro aspecto, ele ainda me soa como um adolescente imatura reclamando da geração anterior.

Answer (score -6):

Eu tenho que discordar em partes do colega acima.

Sobre a metodologia SQA – Software Quality Assurance, que consiste em monitorar os processos de engenharia de software e desenvolvimento. Este princípio se baseia buscar uma forte definição de requerimentos, codificação, refatoração de código, testes, gerenciamento de versões, dentre outros.

Está clara a ideia de que SQA está diretamente ligada com as ideias de comprometimento de Desempenho e Qualidade. Sendo estes mesmo ideais que o TDD busca atingir, estando diretamente ligados segundo minha opinião.

O processo de realizar desenvolvimento de sistemas a partir a testes apareceu inicialmente em meados dos anos 2000 junto a pratica do extreme programming, com a ideia de começar o desenvolvimento pela rotina de testes.

Com manifesto ágil, que trouxe a cultura LEAN para desenvolvimento de software e pratica do extreme programming, vínhamos a tomar uma nova mentalidade para realização do nosso trabalho como desenvolvedores. Viemos a absorver os 5 princípios da mentalidade LEAN:

1. VALOR;
2. FLUXO DE VALOR;
3. FLUXO CONTÍNUO;
4. PRODUÇÃO PUXADA;
5. PERFEIÇÃO.

Mary Poppendieck, que aperfeiçoou a metodologia LEAN para o desenvolvimento de software nos trouxe 8 princípios:

1. Eliminar desperdício;
2. Amplificar conhecimento;
3. Desenvolver com qualidade;
4. Postergar decisões;
5. Entregas rápidas
6. Respeitar as pessoas
7. Melhoria continua;
8. Otimizar como um todo.

Se formos analisar, tanto o pensamento LEAN, quando as praticas do XP, veremos que eles buscam a perfeição do software e entregar um produto de qualidade para o cliente.Sempre se focando na prevenção de falhas, por isso a utilização do TDD.

A utilização do TDD visa justamente desenvolver um software com uma codificação limpa, se baseando na pratica do YAGNI (você não vai precisar disto) e um sistema sem erros, baseado na metodologia LEAN, para entregar um produto de qualidade para o cliente.

Uma boa maneira de se preparar para realizar o TDD, através do assert, é adicionar um critério de aceite nas User Story que dará origem ao código. Ex.

COMO UM ... EU QUERO ... PARA QUE SEJA POSSIVEL ...

Os ... finais irão te ajudar a entender o que deve ser escrito no assert do teu teste, para que a partir dele tu comece a codificar e por fim chegar no resultado esperado.

ps. [Escrevi sobre o assunto em meu blogue](http://gustavoemmel.blogspot.com.br/2014/06/tdd-test-driven-development.html).

Comment: Discordar em que exatamente? Além do mais, *SQA* é diferente de *QA*. E qual o processo que não busca desempenho e qualidade? TDD e SQA estão em extremos opostos da classificação de processos. Enfim, como falar sobre Lean e XP responde de alguma forma a pergunta feita?

Comment: Acredito que quando estamos falando de Quality Assurance e TDD no mesmo tópico não temos como levar o QA para longe do software. Ainda mais, acho escencial mensionar da onde veio a cultura do TDD, que foi exatamente, caso não saibas, da metodologia LEAN da toyota (com bases no jidoka), bem como na cultura XP. Em quais tinham por finalidade melhoria continua e entrega de um produto de qualidade.