# Duvidas sobre testes unitarios

Tags: php, testes-de-unidade

Eu sou novo em testes unitarios e estou com dúvida em algumas aplicações basicas.

Primeiro: o foco do phpunit é verificar se um retorno tem um padrão esperado. Se sim, o teste passou. Se não, lança erro. Porem, sempre que eu uso o `call('POST/GET', 'someRoute')`, ao executar os testes, recebo o resultado html no console. Ao inves de apenas uma verificação. Pra ficar melhor, coloco um `assertResponseOk()` depois do `call()`. Mas o phpunit diz que não existe um status http desse teste.

Segundo: Minha aplicação utiliza repositorios para persistencia no banco de dados. A aplicação funciona perfeitamente. Mas, sempre que eu executo um teste, ele me diz que os repositorios não podem ser instanciados. Qual a diferença de comportamento do phpunit para o server do laravel nesse caso?

Terceiro: (tenham paciencia com essa) Todos os tutoriais sobre testes unitarios dizem: "isole as dependencias". Afinal de contas, o que isso quer dizer?

Quarto: Sobre metodos em controllers que já entregam informações na view. O `View::make()` (entrega de dados a partir de um metodo para uma view no laravel) tem que ficar sempre em um metodo separado? Tipo: um metodo para montar uma coleção de agenda e outro para pegar a coleção da agenda e entregar para uma view. E se uma view precisar de varios dados? Também testo esse metodo? Ou não pois todos os seus dados foram previamente montados e testados?

Agradeço aos que poderem me ajudar com qualquer tipo de informação.
Eu já li varios tutoriais, mas como o proprio Jeffrey Way diz: "testar controladores não é uma das tarefas mais faceis"

Comment: Funções como `call('POST/GET', 'someRoute')` são específicas do [laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#framework-assertions) e não fazem parte do phpunit. Testes unitário se limitam a testar classes isoladamente, e os métodos listados se encaixam mais como testes de integração. Procure também fazer perguntas isoladas. Quatro perguntas no mesmo tópico fica inviável pra qualquer resposta objetiva. Caso queira tirar dúvidas conceituais de testes pode recorrer a essa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19196/4751)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com meritos a João Batista Neto - Desenvolvedor Web no Imaster

Okay, sua questão é sobre testes unitários de forma geral. Você obviamente não compreendeu a intenção nem a motivação para se escrever testes.

Testes unitários tem como intenção verificar se o algorítimo escrito está funcionando segundo seus requisitos. O desenvolvedor é responsável pelo código que escreve. Para poder ser responsável, o desenvolvedor testa seu código para garantir o funcionamento. A motivação é justamente essa: Garantir sua responsabilidade sobre o código escrito.

O foco do PHPUnit, JUnit ou qualquer framework de teste unitário, não é verificar retorno. É verificar o funcionamento de todo o algorítimo.

Quando falamos em orientação a objetos, é comum falarmos sobre SRP - princípio da responsabilidade única. Se você compreende esse princípio, então fica fácil compreender a unidade. Unidade é justamente uma responsabilidade. Cada participante de sua aplicação que tem uma responsabilidade específica é, por definição, uma unidade da aplicação.

Quando você vai escrever um teste unitário, você vai testar aquela unidade específica. Portanto, você deve isolar suas dependências. E você deve isolá-las, pois não é responsabilidade da unidade que está sendo testada, testar outras unidades.

Além disso, existem alguns princípios específicos para testes do ponto de vista do TDD. São os princípios F.I.R.S.T.

F = Os testes precisam ser executados rapidamente. Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre esse princípio, pois sai do escopo da thread.

I = Os testes precisam ser isolados. Aqui entramos num dos pontos que você tocou. Bases de dados, requisições e respostas HTTP. Sempre que você trabalha com coisas externas ao seu código, você corre um risco dessas coisas afetarem o comportamento do código de forma temporária.

O que quebrou? Foi o código, ou o link que caiu?

Para evitar que coisas externas afetem o funcionamento do código, você encapsula essas coisas externas como o protocolo HTTP e bases de dados em mockups. Os mocks funcionam como cenários ideiais para o funcionamento daquilo que é externo.

Esse encapsulamento é importante, pois como você está testando o algorítimo que envia uma requisição ou trata uma resposta, então não tem porquê você ser afetado por um problema de conexão.

R = Os testes precisam poder ser repetidos a qualquer momento e em qualquer ordem. Esse princípio também é afetado por bases de dados. Por exemplo, imagine que você tenha uma base com uma chave primária X. Se você escreve o teste que vai obter uma informação da base, você vai precisar ter essa informação na base, ou seja, você vai precisar gravá-la antes.

Se seu teste de obtenção depende que o teste de gravação ocorra antes, então você tem um problema de design no seu teste, pois você não poderá mudar a ordem dos testes. Novamente, é por isso que criamos mocks para bases de dados. Porque é irrelevante para o algorítimo saber se a informação está efetivamente na base, ou se sequer existe uma base. Você não está testando a base. Ela já tem seus próprios testes.

Você precisa testar o SEU código. Qualquer coisa fora dele, está fora do escopo do teste da unidade.

S = Os testes precisam poder ser executados sem nenhuma intervenção humana. O objetivo disso é efetivamente automatizar os testes. Se toda vez que você for testar, você precisar navegar na aplicação, é possível que você deixe de testá-la. Imagine uma grande aplicação, com centenas ou milhares de páginas. Se você precisar navegar página por página, você não vai conseguir testar seu código e, eventualmente, desistirá dos testes.

T = Os testes precisam ser escritos ANTES do código que os fará passar. Também não vou entrar em detalhes sobre esse princípio pois sai do escopo da thread.

O ponto é que qualquer coisa que não seja especificamente o SEU código deve ser encapsulado e isolado. Testes unitários preocupam-se em testar tão somente o código que você escreveu. Se você focar exclusivamente no seu código e encapsular tudo o que for externo, todas as suas questões serão resolvidas ao mesmo tempo.

E se você compreender tudo o que escrevi no acima, você também compreenderá o porquê de dizermos que TDD é um validador de design.

Veja, temos que enviar uma requisição HTTP e depois tratar a resposta. Quantas responsabilidades existem nesse processo?

1 - Abertura da conexão.
2 - Verificação do estado da conexão.
3 - Envio da requisição.
4 - Verificação do sucesso no envio da requisição.
5 - Leitura da resposta.
6 - Verificação do sucesso da leitura da resposta.
7 - Tratamento da resposta.

Um simples envio de uma requisição HTTP tem, no mínimo, 7 responsabilidades distintas. Todas essas responsabilidades demandam testes específicos.

Quando você trabalha seus testes focando na proposta da unidade, você forçosamente acabará definindo melhor as responsabilidades do seu código e terá um melhor design como um todo.

Comment: Onde exatamente você responde as questões levantadas na pergunta?

Answer (score 3):

Como você colocou muitas coisa em uma pergunta só não fica claro o seu nível de entendimento de testes unitários. Ok, ao final entendi que você quer testar os controlares, mas antes disso, você já trabalha com testes unitários? Já começou/consegiu usar com coisas mais simples?

Muitas vezes o problema é a falta de foco na orientação a objetos. Se não conseguiu usar ainda, sugiro você começar testando serviços. Tudo que for regra de negócios, você mover para novas classes de serviços e testar o retorno dessas classes. Se nao fez isso, é um bom começo. Se já fez, aí fica faltando ver qual o objetivo esperado dos testes com os controlares e os repositórios. Pois no caso do repositório, se você só for testar que o model está persistindo, nao faz sentido, pois você está testando o eloquent e nos sabemos que ele funciona. Apena um exemplo.

Quanto a isolar as dependências, um exemplo clássico, seu sistema depende de um banco de dados. Mas no teste unitário, o ideal é você usar algum Mock Object que abstraia o banco e "isole a dependência" do banco de dados.