# Qual a vantagem de usar JUnit para testar métodos de uma classe?

Tags: java, testes, testes-de-unidade, junit

Eu criei uma aplicação que basicamente é uma classe que testa se os métodos de outra classe estão retornando os valores esperados. Meu professor pediu para que eu refizesse essa classe como um caso de teste do JUnit. Fiz o que ele pediu, mas no final obtenho o mesmo resultado que teria quando uso apenas uma classe normal. Que vantagens posso tirar do JUnit nesse caso?

Comment: Neste caso específico, nenhuma vantagem. Alguém pode argumentar inclusive que é um exagero usar todo um framework para testar uma única classe. Mas conforme sua necessidade por testes aumenta, você terá que implementar outros tipos de verificações e outputs e integrações... Daí o JUnit passa a fazer sentido porque já está implementado nele tudo que você acabaria tendo que implementar por conta própria - outras pessoas tiveram as mesmas necessidades e disponibilizam para você a solução pronta para um problema comum que admite uma solução comum.

Comment: @Caffé Obrigado. Era essa a resposta que eu estava buscando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) é um *framework* para produzir testes. Ele sabe melhor que os programadores como fazer isso de forma correta, está tudo pronto para seu uso. Claro que o programador precisa saber usar.

A vantagem de fazer testes é saber se o método está atendendo os requisitos especificados no próprio teste. Você pode modificar seus métodos normais e rodar o JUnit para saber se suas modificações não comprometeram o resultado do método modificado. Você verá mais vantagens quando estiver lidando com grandes bases de código. Mas vai aprendendo fazer desde o princípio, mesmo em códigos de exercício.

Especificamente o JUnit tem um **jeito estruturado** de manipular os testes e lidar com os resultados dele. Se você escrevê-los da forma como o JUnit exige a ferramenta poderá fazer melhor proveito dessas informações e determinar se está tudo ok, tudo sem intervenção humana. Essa forma pode ajudar a integração com outras ferramentas compatíveis com JUnit.

O bom uso dos seus recursos pode documentar melhor os problemas encontrados se um teste falhar. Isso é útil para diversas ferramentas e para toda equipe. Sempre que você tem uma forma padrão terá o trabalho mais organizado.

Ele, como um todo, pode ajudar criar os testes e dados para confrontar o comportamento, além de facilitar certos tipos de testes que exigiriam uma infraestrutura específica para rodar. Obviamente que ele é só uma ferramenta de automação do processo. Ele não faz seu código ficar melhor, nem faz seus testes estarem corretos. Se os testes forem mal escritos, pouco ou nada ajuda. Ele pode dar produtividade e diminuir a parte chata de escrever testes além de evitar alguns erros comuns e esquecimentos.

Além disso ele incentiva criar os testes antes do código, o chamado [TDD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Sem mencionar que ao usar um framework pra isso depois você pode utilizar ele numa ferramenta de CI, como por exemplo o famoso Jenkins.

Comment: Não citei especificamente esta, falei de ferramentas em geral.

Comment: Sim sim, so mencionei especificamente o Jenkins visto que a pergunta apontou o JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Eu entendo que a grande vantagem é principalmente **uma**, a mesma que me faz usar JAVA: A padronização.

Se você usar uma **"mini framework"** que você fez para testar ao invés de usar uma que já é **testada**, **documentada** e largamente **usada** o que vai acontecer quando você precisar de **300** (ou 3 nem precisa ser exagerado) programadores **desenvolvendo** e **testando** a sua aplicação? Eles vão ter que aprender a usar essa sua framework de testes, não saberão se ela no futuro continuará atendendo, etc. Coisas que quando você usa frameworks de mercado fica muito mais fácil, barato e padronizado de se trabalhar.

Então a moral da história é: É melhor já ir treinando do jeito que o mercado funciona para ser um bom profissional no futuro