# TDD e Teste de unidade, ambos são a mesma coisa e possuem a mesma finalidade?

Tags: terminologia, testes-de-unidade, tdd

Sempre quando leio a respeito de **TDD** (Test Driven Development) ele esta relacionado com **Teste de unidade**, isso me faz acreditar que **TDD** é o mesmo que **Teste de unidade**, e eu não sei se esta minha definição esta correta em relação ao meu ponto de vista. Talvez eu esteja confundindo os termos e misturando os conceitos.

**TDD** e **Teste de unidade** são coisas distintas? Se sim, quais são as diferenças entre eles e qual é a finalidade de cada um em particular?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19177/testes-tdd-unit-test-qa-e-assemelhados-qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-dos-conceitos-sobre)

Comment: @bigown eu li as resposta desta sua pergunta, são tantos conceitos de teste que me confundiu mais ainda, por isso decidi também fazer uma pergunta mias direcionada a TDD e Teste de unidade onde é o ponto que mais me causa confusão, porque ambos são parecidos. Eu não acho que seja duplicata, mais fica a critério da comunidade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

São conceitos distintos. TDD é uma filosofia de desenvolvimento de software: para implementar qualquer funcionalidade (ou fazer alterações no código), você:

1. Cria um (ou mais) teste(s), que provavelmente serão unitários, mas nem sempre
2. Executa o teste, observando que ele vai falhar (é possível que, além do teste, você precise também implementar algo tipo *mocks* para que a compilação funcione)
3. Implementa a funcionalidade / alteração no programa
4. Executa o teste novamente, verifica que ele agora está passando.

Testes de unidades são apenas um componente do TDD (passo 1 do processo acima) - em todo processo de TDD, você terá (muitos) testes unitários, mas não somente eles: testes de integração, com ou sem *mocks*, também são necessários.

E você pode usar testes unitários mesmo sem o TDD. Se você não acredita nessa filosofia (e muitos não a seguem a risca), então você pode desenvolver o software da maneira "tradicional", e post-facto implementar os testes (unitários ou não).

Comment: Falta um quinto passo importante aí: o ***refactoring***. Além disso, não é um "ou mais" testes, é apenas um teste em cada ciclo, podendo-se eventualmente pular o refactoring antes de iniciar o próximo ciclo (técnica chamada "triangulação"). No mais, excelente resposta.

Comment: Vc disse que os testes provavelmente são unitários, mas nem sempre isso ocorre, neste caso qual é o tipo de teste que esta associado ao TDD que não é um teste unitário?

Comment: Testes de integração, por exemplo. Pela definição, testes unitários somente testam uma "unidade". Se você encontrou um bug no seu sistema causado por uma unidade passando um valor errado para uma outra unidade, uma iteração do TDD seria a implementação de um teste com estas duas unidades (que iria falhar, por causa do bug), consertar o bug, e depois verificar que o teste passou. Como este teste está validando duas "unidades", não pode ser considerado estritamente um teste unitário.