# Devo cobrir métodos privados em testes unitários?

Tags: testes, testes-de-unidade

Na minha cobertura de testes unitários, as funções privadas não são testadas.

Não sei se esse é o encaminhamento mais correto. Eu deveria testar meus métodos privados? Todos?

No .NET, o atributo [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) possibilita isso, o que me deixou com essa dúvida (embora a pergunta não se limite a esse *framework*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De maneira geral não deveria. Métodos privados usados adequadamente são detalhes de implementação e o objetivo dos testes de unidade ([teste unitário é um termo errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/567879/101)) é testar a API pública e não o detalhe.

O método privado é só um auxiliar para os métodos públicos, então não importa o que muda nele ou se ele está dando o resultado correto, importa se os públicos estão dando o resultado correto. Se o privado estiver errado o público certamente estará errado, e é ele que não pode ficar errado.

O teste de unidade não tem que mostrar onde está o erro, apenas que há um erro quando se usa a API conforme se espera, ou que o uso de forma inesperada não é devidamente tratado.

Pra tudo tem exceção e há casos que você pode fazer isso, só não é o normal. Tanto que há controvérsias. Pode ver nas [respostas no SO que as mais votadas dizem coisas opostas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/105007/221800). Eu diria que testar os privados é algo que vai além ao teste de unidade, mas pode ser feito como forma de proteção extra e dar mais subsídios para o teste.

O .NET fornece meios para trabalhar com "todos" os estilos. O [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) não serve só para isso.

- [Para que servem Testes Unitários e quais as vantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53678/101)
- [TDD e Teste de unidade, ambos são a mesma coisa e possuem a mesma finalidade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130641/101)
- [Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101)
- [Teste unitário é um termo genérico? Quais tipos existem? E quais formas de aplicar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/233197/101)

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Answer (score 3):

Em principio não deveria ser necessário testá-los.

Um método privado, se existe, é para ser chamado.

Assim irá ser utilizado directa ou indirectamente por um método publico.

Se os teste que implementar cobrirem todos os métodos públicos, então os métodos privados também estão cobertos.