# Qual a diferença entre teste e depuração?

Tags: terminologia, testes, debug, princípios-de-programação

No livro "Introdução ao Teste de Software" de Ammann & Offutt menciona na  p.32 os 5 níveis modelos de maturidade de teste de software:

> - Nível 0 - Não há diferença entre teste e depuração.
> - Nível 1 - A finalidade de um teste é mostrar que um software funciona.
> - Nível 2 - A finalidade de um teste é mostrar que o software não funciona.
> - Nível 3 - A finalidade de um teste não é provar nada em específico, mas reduzir os riscos de uso do software.
> - Nível 4 - Teste de software é uma disciplina mental que ajuda todos os profissionais de TI a desenvolverem softwares de qualidade.

Apesar de não entrar em detalhes sobre depuração. Qual a diferença entre teste e depuração?

PS: pergunta traduzida de [uma pergunta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79068/what-is-the-difference-between-debugging-and-testing) na comunidade programmers (en)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Teste

Na pergunta já tem uma boa definição sobre testes. Tem uma definição mais em ampla em [Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101).

Então podemos concluir que ele é uma medida para "garantir" qualidade. Você verifica se o software está conforme.

É um processo do desenvolvimento como um todo. Testes duram em todo o ciclo de vida do projeto.

Novos testes são sempre desejáveis. Se um problema for detectado por outros meios (uma depuração, por exemplo), um teste para garantir que o problema não volte ocorrer é interessante.

Testes são feitos com ferramentas específicas que automatizam o processo e códigos que possui a função de dizer se algo bem específico gerando o resultado esperado ou não.

A preocupação é com o resultado, não como se chegou nele.

Teste é para identificar quando um código está correto, não quando ele tem problema. Um erro comum é as pessoas acreditarem que se passar no teste há ausência de problemas do código, mas ele só diz que certas situações aconteceram corretamente, não pode inverter a lógica de que se passou no teste não há *bugs*.

## Depuração

Depuração é um processo de conserto de algo que sabe-se estar quebrado.

Em geral é pontual para um defeito.

Muitas vezes o processo é iniciado porque um teste detetou que há esse defeito.

É algo que simula-se a execução passo a passo manualmente para achar o motivo do problema e determinar o que precisaria ser mudado para resolvê-lo.

Em geral é feito com o auxílio de ferramentas adicionais ou código extra para determinar o que está acontecendo e no final quando o problema é resolvido aquilo é jogado fora.

O foco é o detalhe da execução, há uma preocupação com o algoritmo e as mudanças de estado.

> Todo mundo sabe que a depuração é duas vezes mais difícil do que escrever um programa em primeiro lugar. Então, se você for tão inteligente quanto pode, quando escrevê-lo, porque você vai depurá-lo?
>
> -- Brian Kernighan

O que eu gostaria mesmo é que as pessoas que resolvem programar aprendessem pelo menos o básico da depuração, o que já ajuda entender um pouco melhor o que ela está fazendo. Em tempos que "programar" virou copiar códigos prontos e preencher lacunas sem entender o que está fazendo, saber depurar parece ser algo desnecessário. Por sorte ainda temos profissionais interessados em fazer o melhor possível e entender o processo completo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).