# Qual a diferença entre o modo Debug e Release?

Tags: c++, qt, debug, mingw, release

Comecei a ter o erro: "Microsoft C++ runtime error library". E obtive muitos problemas ao tentar concertar este erro.

Eu estava utilizando o Qt Creator com mingw32 no modo *debug*, mas percebi que este modo depende de muitas DLLs do compilador.

Eu sei que existe o modo *release* para a construção do programa, a minha dúvida é, qual a diferença dos dois modos?

Utilizar o *release* é mais vantajoso do que o *debug* pelo MingW?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é questão de ser mais vantajoso, como o próprio nome diz um é para efeitos de [depuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149424/101) e o outro é para efeitos de liberação (colocar em produção).

O modo de *debug* possui muito mais informações disponíveis para que o software de *debug* possa ajudar mais o programador depurar seu código. Por ter muito mais informação, não necessária para a execução normal da aplicação, é claro que são códigos muito mais pesados.

Na verdade mandar informações de depuração em uma aplicação final pode ser considerado até uma falha de segurança.

Não importa a linguagem, biblioteca, compilador, ou qualquer coisa do tipo, é algo universal.

O Microsoft C++ Runtime é necessário independente de ser *debug* ou *release*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer minha dúvida!