# Por que o C++ demora muito mais para compilar que outras linguagens?

Tags: java, c#, c++, desempenho, compiladores

Dá para notar fácil que compilar com C++ é muito mais demorado que em C#, Java e outras linguagens. E vale para todos os compiladores.

O que faz a linguagem demorar tanto?

Comment: Achei que era o motivo do nome `C++` (`C` com `mais` e `mais` tempo pra compilar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De fato, C++ demora mais para compilar, tipicamente. Pode acontecer casos excepcionais. Vejamos:

## Linguagem contextual

C++ não consegue ser compilada de forma simples, muito em função do legado do C ou de versões iniciais de C++ que ela precisa carregar até hoje, e também por algumas decisões ruins.

Normalmente os *parsers* dos compiladores costumam avançar em até um *token* à frente do atual para decidir o que é esse *token*. Em C++ precisa avançar vários *tokens* em muitos casos para estabelecer contexto. Em alguns casos pode nem conseguir no mesmo passo do compilador. Isso complica imensamente o compilador e faz ele trabalhar bem mais para eliminar as ambiguidades.

## Arquivos de cabeçalho/pré-processador

Isso sempre foi um enorme problema para a linguagem porque é outro passo de compilação, é algo fora da linguagem normal, e muitas vezes tem que ficar compilando enormes arquivos para determinar o que fazer com o código.

Em muitos casos fica compilando o mesmo repetidas vezes.

É verdade que algumas implementações adotaram um sistema de cache, mas ele precisa ser ativado e nem todo mundo sabe fazer adequadamente, ou funciona como o esperado. E as versões mais novas do C++ estão permitindo usar [módulos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules), que reduz a necessidade dos cabeçalhos, mas não elimina.

## *Templates*

Esse pode ser um dos maiores problemas. [Ao contrário de Java e C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101) que não traduzem o código genérico para uma explosão de novos tipos, C++ faz isso com um mecanismo de geração de código, o que faz muito mais código do que você vê escrito ser compilado.

Imagina um simples `vector` sendo usado para 10 tipos diferentes, são declarações inteirinhas do `vector` que são geradas e compiladas 10 vezes.

É pior em uma `map` que tem dois parâmetros. Com apenas 5 tipos pode haver uma explosão de dezenas de tipos para criar, se usar todas as combinações possíveis.

E quase sempre isso é gerado diversas vezes. Em cada unidade de compilação uma nova versão do tipo é gerado em novo código fonte, mesmo que já tenha sido gerado em outra unidade, então compila algo que já estava pronto. Para resolver isso pode ficar mais complicado ainda.

## *Linkagem*

O processo de geração do executável já precisa juntar tudo que a aplicação vai usar fazendo o [*linking*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101), que pode ser bem pesado em alguns casos. Existem maneiras de reduzir essa necessidade. Isso significa que tem que gerar o código final e que precisa resolver tudo que é necessário, não pode fazer um processo inicial para terminar depois o resto durante a execução.

## Otimização

Certamente isso é o que toma mais tempo de compilação em modo [*release*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149966/101). Otimização pesada toma muito tempo, e C++ tem a filosofia de fazer isso ao extremo. Até mesmo para *linkar* costuma gastar muito processamento para atingir o objetivo.

C# ou Java fazem pouca otimização, algumas são deixadas para a execução ([*JITting*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101)), então pode ir muito mais rápido.

Isso não costuma ser um problema em modo *debug* que é onde o pessoal mais reclama. Para o resultado final em geral o tempo alto é aceitável, o problema é o ciclo de desenvolvimento onde se compila com muita frequência.

## *Linting*

Alguns compiladores fazem alguma forma de *Lint* para detectar alguns erros que são comuns nos códigos. Em C++ isso tende ser mais importante por ela dar muita liberdade, em alguns casos pelo legado. Em muitos compiladores algumas análises extras (além da especificação da linguagem) são padrões, e muitas podem custar caro, até por isso talvez não façam parte da linguagem.

## Mensagens de erro

Mais recentemente os compiladores passaram dar melhores mensagens de erro. Por causa de vários dos itens acima os erros de C++ sempre foram pouco úteis. Para melhorar isso os compiladores passaram fazer uma análise mais profunda para achar um contexto maior e ter subsídios para dar melhores mensagens de erro. Isso piorou a situação.

## Conclusão

Muito é por causa do legado, há movimentos para quebrar isso, mas nunca passarão no comitê da linguagem porque fará ela ser outra linguagem. O que dá para fazer está sendo feito. Algumas propostas pioram a situação.

Ao contrário da crença popular, os computadores estão com limitações de desempenho e é preciso escolher ferramentas que entregam melhor resultado se deseja isso. Em geral as pessoas preferem pagar esse preço para ter a linguagem que melhor atende seus objetivos.

Rust consegue ser pior em alguns casos mesmo não tendo esse legado todo. Mas ela fornece algumas coisas que C++ não costuma fornecer, a não ser com *linting* extra, o que faria a compilação de C++ ficar bem lenta se incluir esse *linting* no *pipeline* da compilação.

C é bem mais rápido, mas tem suas dificuldades. Tem linguagens que foram pensadas para compilar rápido, Go é uma delas. Pascal sempre foi assim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).