# Como funciona o Teste de Caixa Branca?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, testes, independente-de-linguagem

Eu li nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19196/27190) do usuário [utluiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz) a seguinte descrição do Teste de Caixa Branca, veja:

> **Teste de caixa branca**: quando se avalia o funcionamento interno do
> software. Por exemplo, se determinados métodos executam corretamente.

Entretanto, continuo com dúvidas a respeito deste tipo de teste.

## Dúvidas

1. Como é executado o teste de caixa branca?
2. Este teste está relacionado a apenas métodos de uma determinada
   classe?
3. Que tipos de métodos eu devo submeter ao teste de caixa branca?

<sup>Eu gostaria de um exemplo prático de um teste de caixa branca sendo aplicado num método, se possível.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testes de caixa branca avalivam o comportamento de uma funcionalidade. Se determinada entrada irá produzir a saída esperada ou se código passou pelo fluxo desejado. Para executar esse tipo de teste é necessário conhecimento do código fonte (diferente de um teste de caixa preta onde apenas o resutlado é avalidado).

> 1 .Como é executado o teste de caixa branca?

A maneira mais formal de faze-lo  é utilizar uma bateria de testes unitário também é possível simplificar separando uma porção do código e criar um novo projeto/arquivo para essa finalidade.

> 2. Este teste está relacionado a apenas métodos de uma determinada classe?

Não, o teste pode verificar se determinada parte foi executada ou não como também pode testar um método inteiro.

Algumas ferramentes de testes unitários fornecem diagnósticos baseados nos casos de testes e dizem quais linhas/trechos de códigos não foram executados, que serve como indicação que nem todos os caminhos foram executados ou existe código morto.

> 3. Que tipos de métodos eu devo submeter ao teste de caixa branca?

Qualquer tipo especialmente os tem alguma validação ou aplicação de regra de négocio.