# Um teste de instrumentação é um teste de integração?

Tags: android, terminologia, testes

Eu vi alguns vídeos onde explicam como testar a chamada de uma atividade por outra atividade.

Eu fiz o seguinte teste e, depois de uma reflexão, não tinha a certeza se o teste que executei era de integração, instrumentação ou teste funcional.

```
public class OneActivityTest {

    private OneActivity mActivity = null;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<OneActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(OneActivity.class);

    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(TwoActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mActivity = mActivityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void checkYes() {

        Assert.assertNotNull(mActivity.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_sim));

        onView(withId(R.id.checkbox_sim)).perform(click());

        Assert.assertNotNull(mActivity.findViewById(R.id.save));

        onView(withId(R.id.save)).perform(click());

        Activity secondActivity = getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(monitor, 5000);

        Assert.assertNotNull(secondActivity);

        secondActivity.finish();
    }
}
```

Ele poderá ser considerado Teste de integração pelo simples facto de interagir com mais do que 1 activity?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19177/testes-tdd-unit-test-qa-e-assemelhados-qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-dos-conceitos-sobre)

Comment: Acredito que não seja duplicata. O AP quer identificar um tipo de teste a partir de um trecho de código.

Comment: agradeço desde já a tentativa de ajuda, mas como referi acima eu vi algumas explicações e fico mesmo sem compreender que tipo de teste é o que eu implementei...analisei o que sugeriu e a minha duvida permanece @Bruno Costa

Comment: Sério Nokas? O que o nome da classe `Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor`, que você está a usar, lhe diz?

Comment: comprendo o que me quer dizer @ramaral, mas a toda a informação que li esta a confundir bastante. mostro no comentário abaixo a confusão que me encontro neste momento

Comment: Testes de integração em Android - O Android Studio faz uma separação dos diferentes grupos de testes para aplicativos da plataforma Android. E essa separação pode ser feita da seguinte forma: Unit Tests: são executados na JVM (Java Virtual Machine), não acessam a API real de Android e, por consequência, não necessitam de um emulador Instrumentation Tests: acessam a API real de Android e, logo, precisam que um emulador esteja disponível para a execução de seus testes Logo, testes de integração, no contexo de desenvolvimento Android, são definidos como instrumentation tests @ramaral

Comment: segundo o que diz nesse texto, então testes de integração são considerados testes de instrumentação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os teste de integração visam verificar se o resultado da interacção entre as diversas partes/componentes da aplicação é o esperado.

Os teste instrumentais visam simular a interacção do usuário, via UI, com a aplicação.
Eles verificam se, a uma determinada acção na UI, a aplicação responde como esperado.
Ao fazê-lo, testam a integração da UI com o resto da aplicação e por isso são testes de integração.