# Qual a diferença entre "test" e "spec" em testes automatizados?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, engenharia-de-software, testes

<sub>A pergunta e duvidas abaixo abordam Node.js, TypeScript e JavaScript. Não sei se os conceitos abaixo se aplicam a outras plataformas/linguagens de programação.</sub>

---

Estou estudando sobre testes automatizados (TA) usando Jest e TypeScript e me surgiu uma dúvida quanto a nomeação dos arquivos de testes. Em alguns projetos que analisei, alguns arquivos estão sendo nomeados de maneira diferente. Alguns possuem a nomenclatura `.test.ts` e outros `.spec.ts`. Até o presente momento da publicação desta pergunta, eu tinha em mente que `test` ou `spec` não tinham nenhuma diferença semântica, ambos serviam apenas para identificar que aquele arquivo é um arquivo de teste, porém as distintas nomeações dos arquivos fez surgir a dúvida sobre o assunto.

Estudando e pesquisando sobre TA, encontrei boas respostas sobre o assunto que me ajudou a entender bastante do conceito, mas nada que esclarecesse minha duvida. Por exemplo, esta [excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19177/testes-tdd-unit-test-qa-e-assemelhados-qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-dos-conceitos-sobre) do @utluiz em que fala sobre conceitos de testes, eu destaco 2 seguintes pontos:

1. > Teste Unitário: testa partes específicas do sistema, como classes e métodos.
2. > Teste de Integração: testa vários componentes de um sistema funcionando de uma só vez.

Vamos ter essa afirmação em mente.

Agora vamos de código para exemplificar a minha dúvida. Na pasta de testes, tenho 2 arquivos de testes que basicamente o que eles fazem é testar o recurso de cadastrar um novo administrador no sistema. Agora vamos ao primeiro arquivo e ainda vou destacar o nome do arquivo:

- O primeiro se chama `admin-signup.test.ts` e neste arquivo de teste, ele injeta ***mocks*** de dependências para dentro do módulo de serviço (`AdminServices`):

```js
import * as AdminServices from '@naointeressa';

const adminData =  {...}

const AdminRepositoryMock =  {...}

const validatorMock =  {...}

const bcryptMockValidPass = {...}

describe('any', () => {
  it('should ...', async () => {
    const sut = await AdminServices.createAdminService(
      AdminRepositoryMock,
      validatorMock,
      bcryptMockValidPass
    )
    const newAdmin = await sut.createAdmin(adminData)

    expect(newAdmin.name).toBeDefined()
    expect(newAdmin.email).toBeDefined()
  })

  ...
})
```

- O segundo se chama `admin-signup.spec.ts` e este se difere do anterior pois ele não injeta *mocks*, mas sim as verdadeiras dependências do módulo de serviço (`AdminServices`):

```js
import * as AdminServices from '@naointeressa';
import * as AdminRepository from '@naointeressa';
import * as crypto from '@naointeressa';
import validator from '@naointeressa';

describe('any', () => {
  it('should ...', async () => {
    const sut = await AdminServices.createAdminService(
      AdminRepository,
      validator,
      cryptoObject,
    );
    const newAdmin = await sut.createAdmin(adminData);

    expect(newAdmin.name).toBeDefined();
    expect(newAdmin.email).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Foi nesse código (simplificado obviamente) que me surgiu essa duvida em relação a nomeação dos arquivos de testes.

Eu fiz uma análise dos exemplos acima citados e cheguei ao seguinte pensamento:

- Usamos `.test.ts` quando o nosso arquivo de teste não testa nenhum recurso externo da nossa aplicação (banco de dados, API externas, chamadas HTTP, etc...), ou seja, para testes que seguem a citação `1` da resposta do @utluiz.
- Usamos `.spec.ts` quando o teste atravessa camadas externas da aplicação (outros módulos, bibliotecas, banco de dados, etc...), ou seja, para a citação `2` da resposta do @utluiz. Testes *end-2-end* também teriam esse tipo de nomenclatura de arquivos (citação `Teste de Sistema` na resposta do @utluiz, me corrijam se estiver errado).

**Porém** não estou seguro da minha conclusão acima. Estou estudando mais sobre testes e ainda fico com algumas duvidas, então, sobre a minha duvida de nomenclaturas, eu pergunto:

1. Existem diferenças semânticas entre nomear um arquivo como `.test.ts` e `.spec.ts`?
2. Se a reposta da pergunta acima é sim, o meu pensamento sobre onde usar determinada nomenclatura está correto? Se não, e qual contexto eu devo usar um ou outro?
3. Ou se não existe diferença semântica entre os nomes, posso adotar qualquer um, e todos eles tem o mesmo propósito... indicar que um arquivo é um arquivo de teste?

---

Cheguei a pensar que `spec` vem de algo específico, ou seja, se o teste testa uma funcionalidade muito simples e minúscula da aplicação como por exemplo uma função que verifica se um campo de email não é vazio (`''`) e só, nada a mais. Mas não me ajudou a sanar a duvida. Gostaria de uma resposta definitiva.

Comment: Não acho que a pergunta tenha relação com TypeScript ao ponto de justificar a tag.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Acho que tem sim pois está com cara do conceito ter vindo daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37502922/2241463

Comment: É, @Piovezan, pode ser.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Senti um certo ar contrariado aí :) Eu não entendo disso, só fiquei curioso sobre o tal termo "spec" sendo aplicado a testes automatizados e fui procurar o que poderia ser, mas não me aprofundei na pesquisa para chegar a uma conclusão definitiva.

Comment: @Piovezan, nada disso!! :P Foi apenas concordância mesmo. :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Existem diferenças semânticas entre nomear um arquivo como `.test.ts` e `.spec.ts`?

Não formalmente. O Jest não convenciona nenhum tipo de "sufixo" no nome do arquivo. Acaba sendo uma convenção adotada por alguns grupos de pessoa para organizar melhor as próprias *suites* de testes.

A maioria das pessoas, pelo que vejo, utiliza somente um dos sufixos. Como `.test.js` **ou** `.spec.js`. Vai do gosto e da forma como a pessoa escreve os testes – como disse, não tem regra oficial.

Pode-se dizer que, testes escritos em formato que mais se assemelham a uma especificação, utilizar `.spec.js` seja mais "semanticamente correto". Vai por aí.

---

> Se a reposta da pergunta acima é sim, o meu pensamento sobre onde usar determinada nomenclatura está correto? Se não, e qual contexto eu devo usar um ou outro?

A resposta da pergunta anterior foi **não** – a nível oficial do Jest. No entanto, desenvolvedores de uma organização podem, por exemplo, **convencionar** o uso de `.test.js` para uma coisa e `.spec.js` para outra.

Nesse caso, cria-se uma diferenciação semântica, mas é limitada à entidade que a estabeleceu.

Quando essa distinção é criada, pode-se, por exemplo, utilizar assim:

- `.spec.js` para testes que visam especificar alguma parte do código (como documentar uma *feature* através de código, por exemplo). Nesse sentido, é mais comumente utilizado no contexto de testes unitários.
- `.test.js` para os demais. Como testes de integração mais genéricos no qual o objetivo não é criar uma "especificação em código".

Mas no geral não é nada *maior* que isso, até porque o nome do arquivo pouco interfere no funcionamento dos testes. O importante, como muita coisa na programação, é a manutenção da consistência. Nesse sentido, como o Jest não convencionada nada em relação à nomenclatura dos arquivos, cabe ao desenvolvedor escolher ou criar uma convenção e tentar a seguir sem muitos desvios.

---

> Ou se não existe diferença semântica entre os nomes, posso adotar qualquer um, e todos eles tem o mesmo propósito... indicar que um arquivo é um arquivo de teste?

Teste é teste. Essa é a semântica. No caso de uma diferença significativa entre o funcionamento dos testes (como integração ou unidade), *pode* fazer sentido semântico mudar a "convenção de sufixos" para refletir a semântica estabelecida. Vai do programador (ou da equipe – ou seja lá quem toma as decisões :P).

Utiliza-se um sufixo como `.test.js` ou `.spec.js` para que o *test runner* consiga achar os arquivos de teste mais facilmente, sem precisar analisar o arquivo em si. A partir daí o programador pode customizar como a busca será feita e customizar a nomenclatura.

No seu caso, você utilizou `.spec.js` para integração e `.test.js` para unidade. Mas tenha certeza que há quem faz o contrário (e está tudo bem).

---

<sup>Note que procurei ser pouco assertivo nesta resposta, uma vez que esse tópico é extremamente subjetivo e altamente fragmentado (no sentido de que é muito comum ver várias pessoas utilizarem convenções distintas). Claro que há convenções mais comuns, mas ainda sim são convenções não oficiais.</sup>

Comment: _"Teste é teste"_ , vou tatuar no meu braço! Foi uma excelente resposta, deu pra entender que para o exemplo acima citado foi apenas um padrão interno adotado. Nos meu testes, fiz ajustes para que no config do Jest, testes unitários façam match de arquivos `.test` e para testes de integ. ou e2e façam match de arquivos `.spec`. Nesse caso, como é uma escolha livre, decidir distinguir do jeito que achei melhor para especificar o tipo de teste a ser executado.