# Qual a diferença entre teste funcional e teste unitário? Seria um unitario um teste funcional?

Tags: testes, testes-de-unidade

Qual a diferença entre teste **funcional** e teste **unitário**?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101

Comment: Não entendi. Teste unitário é um teste funcional?

Comment: Acho que não... o post nao fala nada sobre teste funcional. Se fala, não entendi. Teste unitário é teste funcional?

Comment: Está lá na resposta: *"... **Teste** é o termo mais geral para ver se um determinado software **funciona**..."*

Comment: Sim! Mas me refiro ao termo teste **funcional**

Comment: Tá na resposta linkada, os *Testes Funcionais* quanto ao conhecimento sobre o software se dividem em Teste de caixa branca e Teste de caixa preta. Quanto à natureza do teste Teste Unitário, Teste de Integração, Teste Homologação, Teste de Aceitação e Teste de Regressão. Já testes não funcionais são: Teste de Performance, Teste de Carga e Teste de Resiliencia.

Comment: Entendi, finalmente! kkkkkk Muito obrigada.