# TDD em função existente (Django)

Tags: django, testes, tdd

Estou precisando aprender mais sobre TDD.

Como deveria ser um teste para isso passar?

A função já funciona, só queria saber como seria um teste?

```
@login_required
def create_contract(request, proposal_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        proposal = Proposal.objects.get(pk=proposal_id)

        if proposal.status != 'co':
            return HttpResponse('O status do orçamento deve ser concluido.')
        else:
            contractor = proposal.work.
customer
            contract = Contract(
                proposal=proposal,
                contractor=contractor
            )
            contract.save()
            proposal.status = 'a'
            proposal.save()
    return redirect('/contract/%d' % contract.id)
```

Answer (score 7):

## TDD não é teste unitário

TDD é uma metodologia de desenvolvimento de software ou muitas vezes funciona como um conjunto de princípios onde os testes exercem um papel fundamental.

O que você está querendo é fazer testes unitários. Claro que isso tem tudo a ver com TDD, mas não confunda as duas coisas.

Não vou entrar em detalhes, pois já escrevi sobre isso, como você pode ler em algumas de minhas outras respostas:

- [Como efetuar TDD na camada Service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19028/227)
- [Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19196/227)

## Pensando nos cenários

Cenários de um teste são as diferentes situações que você quer tester. Em geral inclui-se:

- **Cenários de sucesso**: aqueles cuja rotina funciona como esperado.
- **Cenários de erro/falha/fracasso/excepcionais**: aqueles onde você simula uma situação de erro para testar o quanto seu código é robusto.

Note algumas pessoas diferenciam cenários excepcionais de cenários de erros, onde o primeiro seria um erro esperado e o segundo um erro inesperado.

Outra diferenciação que faz sentido em alguns contextos é diferenciar o cenário principal dos cenários alternativos.

Por exemplo, no caso da rotina citada na pergunta, analisando os condicionais do código, a princípio vejo três cenários:

1. Usuário autenticado e proposta com status `co` (sucesso)
2. Usuário autenticado e proposta com status diferente de `co` (excepcional)
3. Usuário não autenticado (excepcional)

Pensando um pouco mais em cenários de erro, o que ocorreria se algum método chamado de objetos cuja rotina depende retornassem valores inesperados? Vejamos:

- Proposta não existe e proposal não contém uma proposta de verdade. O que ocorre?
- Ocorre um erro em algum método `save` (falha ao acessar o banco, por exemplo). O que ocorre?

Não me parece o caso desta rotina, mas se estiver implementando uma API, isto é, um código que vai ser usado por terceiros, é sempre bom testar também cenários onde os parâmetros são nulos ou diferentes do esperado (ou pelo menos documentar o comportamento esperado nesses casos).

## Criando o ambiente para um teste unitário

O mais importante em um teste unitário é que ele seja unitário de verdade. Para isso o ideal é que a rotina não dependa do funcionamento de mecanismos externos

Por exemplo, você não vai querer o teste dependendo de ter uma proposta cadastrada no banco de dados e então ter esse banco configurado cada vez que vai executar a rotina.

Claro que às vezes desejamos executar um teste de integração que testa vários objetos atuando em conjunto e até acessando o banco, mas vamos ignorar essa abordagem por enquanto.

Um problema que você pode enfrentar nesse código é o acesso direto ou estático a objetos externos. Em alguns casos isso é facilmente contornável, pois é um acesso planejado pela plataforma, em outros pode ser tornar o código bem difícil de testar. No caso dessa rotina, você pode simplesmente popular o seu repositório com dados como no [primeiro exemplo da documentação de testes do framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/).

Outro problema desse método é que ele faz muita coisa. Além de aplicar lógica de navegação que um *controller* deveria fazer, ele também faz a criação de objetos e manipulação de várias entidades no banco. Eu sei que parece exagero, mas uma leve mudança de mentalidade pode fazer enxergar que essa divisão faz sentido e deixaria o código menos acoplado e mais fácil de testar.

Exemplo:

```
@login_required
def create_contract(request, proposal_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if my_model.is_proposal_budget_completed(proposal_id):
            return HttpResponse('O status do orçamento deve ser concluido.')
        else:
            my_model.create_contract_using_proposal(proposal_id)
    return redirect('/contract/%d' % contract.id)
```

Note como agora é mais fácil entender o que o método faz e a lógica está abstraída num *model*, podendo ser reutilizada e também substituída usando *mocks* para teste.

Um *mock* é um objeto substituto que colocamos no lugar do verdadeiro. Ele simula o objeto verdadeiro em nosso teste, retornando valores pré-definidos para que seu comportamento não interfira no resultado do teste.

## Implementando os testes

Para realizar um teste unitário na rotina, basta construir manualmente os parâmetros necessários para cada cenário que se quer testar, chamar a rotina com esses parâmetros e finalmente fazer uma asserção para garantir que o resultado é o esperado.

Por exemplo, no cenário de sucesso, você pode verificar se o retorno do método, que é um `HttpResponseRedirect` retornado por [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) possui os valores esperados.

Outra possibilidade (embora eu não saiba como fazer isso em Python, é verificar se os métodos que deveriam ser chamados foram realmente chamados e com os valores corretos.

Num cenário excepcional com `status != 'co'`, basta verificar a mensagem retornada no `HttpResponse`.

Lembre-se de sempre consultar a [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/) da linguagem e do framework que está usando, pois eles sempre fornecem um ou mais métodos para testar de forma integrada.

Comment: tudo isso ainda é muito novo pra mim, tem como vc me dar uns exemplos?

Answer (score 3):

Tdd trabalha com um ciclo:
test fail >> test pass >> refactory >> test fail >> test pass >> test refactory

É bem complicado passar um exemplo exemplo exato porque é você que tem que saber isso.
Mas..
Cada teste tem um cenário, ou seja, você quer que algo aconteça, faz o teste para ver se esse algo acontece e isso te gera uma falha.
Partindo dessa falha, você programa e faz o teste passar.

O conceito do "refactory", é quando você vê que o seu código não está bom e pode ser melhorado, e com isso você repete o ciclo:
... >> Refactory (melhoria do código) >> test fail >> test pass >> Refactory.

**Isso envolve um pouco de bom senso e você julgar se o seu próprio código está bom ou não para você refatorar.**

No caso da sua view, eu identifico alguns cenários:

1 - Se o status for diferente de 'co', exibir o HttpResponse;
2 - Se o status for diferente de 'co', salvar o contract;
3 - Verificar se o proposal alterou o status code após o salvamento de tudo.

Por "baixo", vejo esses 3 testes iniciais.

Para trabalhar com tests, você pode seguir por esse caminho:

1 - Instalar dependências:

```
django-nose==1.4 - Ajudará a executar seus tests
model-mommy==1.2.5.1 - Ajudará a criar objetos para seus tests
```

2 - Criar um settings_tests.py no mesmo diretório do settings do seu projeto para executar seus tests. Ele servirá para você criar objetos em um banco de test que depois serão destruídos. Exemplo:

```
    # coding: utf-8
    import logging
    from .settings import *

    logging.disable(logging.INFO)

    DEBUG = True

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME':':memory:',
        }
    }
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    )

    TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
    BROKER_BACKEND = 'memory'
    SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
    SKIP_SLOW_TESTS = True
    RUN_SLOW_TESTS = False
```

3 - Primeiro test
    Por padrão, cada app já vem com o arquivo tests.py, em que você pode colocar seus tests ali.
    Tudo rodando certo, você deve executar o seguinte comando:

```
python manage.py test --settings=seu_projeto.settings_tests
```

Tudo estando certo, você irá ver a mensagem de que não existem tests.
Criando uma classe básica para test, você tem o seu setup, ou seja, o seu test sempre passará por ali inicialmente para executar seus tests.
É sempre importante observar o que sua view/classe espera receber para você enviar para ela antes de chamá-la. No seu caso, a sua view espera o "proposal_id", e por isso você deve enviar este valor.

```
    class MinhaClasseTest(TestCase):

        def setUp(self):
            #isso criará um objeto temporário para o seu test
            self.proposal = mommy.make(Proposal) # from model_mommy import mommy e from .models import Proposal

        def test_status_is_not_co(self):
            self.proposal.status = 'co'
            self.proposal.save()
            resposta = self.client.get('/url-que-chama-essa-view/'+self.proposal.id)
            esperado = 'O status do orçamento deve ser concluido.'
            self.assertEqual(resposta, esperado)
```

É muito importante observar que o test ideal será dito por você, o cenário ideal será dito por você. 
Você é que sabe o que você espera da chamada de um método ou classe, e esse é o esperado do seu test.