# O TDD (Test-Driven Development) melhora o design?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, tdd

Algumas pessoas dizem que o TDD (Desenvolvimento Guiado por Testes) é responsável por melhorar o *design* das classes do projeto. Outras dizem que isso não acontece ou não é necessariamente verdade. O TDD por si só, **sem nenhum tipo de *design* preliminar**, tem evidências que realmente produz um bom *design*?

Versão tupiniquim dessa pergunta: [Does TDD lead to good design?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178856/does-tdd-lead-to-good-design)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O próprio Uncle Bob que defende tanto o TDD diz que o que faz o *design* ser bom é o programador. E eu não poderia concordar mais.

Se a pessoa achar que TDD é bala de prata vai dar tudo errado. E é comum que as pessoas que mais acham isso é que usam errado.

Sabendo fazer TDD pode ser útil. O problema é que para fazer certo precisa ser muito bom em entender problemas complexos como um todo e observar cada mínimo detalhe. Se a pessoa tiver capacidade para isso é uma que pouco se beneficiará do TDD, o que é um paradoxo.

## Testes

Vamos entender que testar é bom. Ninguém discute isso. E testar para **não funcionar** é até mais importante que testar para funcionar, o que é uma minoria que faz. A imensa maioria dos programadores só testam para ver funcionando.

Testes de unidade não deixam você cometer o mesmo erro novamente e não deixam ter regressão. Como consequência haverá um pouco menos *bugs*. Mas não chega nem perto fazer um software *bug free*.

Pra mim, testes de unidade e TDD servem pra propósitos diferentes apesar de usaram a mesma técnica. Teste de unidade testa o que você sabe que precisa ser testado. TDD tenta definir o que será o projeto. Mas quando você está desenvolvendo percebe que algumas coisas não funcionam como esperava. Aí muda o TDD? Então porque fez o TDD?

Ele ajuda você pensar o problema? Se você começar com um protótipo e ir melhorando não dá na mesma?

## Não há provas

O fato é que não há provas que o TDD é eficaz e mesmo [alguns usuários antigos hoje não usam mais](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/2014/tdd-is-dead-long-live-testing.html). Se a pessoa se sente confortável com ele, se acredita que ele está ajudando, ok, bom para essa pessoa. Se a pessoa quer que outras pessoas adotem o TDD, que ofereça provas criteriosas que ele é bom. Tudo o que existe sobre TDD diz que é bom e você deve acreditar nisso. Parece seita.

Eu já dei uma resposta antes que dizia que TDD é bom quando você tem uma clara especificação muito bem feita. Raros problemas são assim. Linguagens de programação são. Não conheço uma só linguagem de programação que tem um compilador desenvolvido com TDD. São softwares desenvolvidos por alguns dos melhores desenvolvedores que você pode encontrar. Por que será que eles optaram por não usar TDD?

## Penduricalhos

Mas eu fico pensando o quanto o *design* muda só para poder fazer o código testável. Isso ajuda o *design*? Alguns dizem que sim. Eu acho que coloca penduricalhos que não servem ao domínio, que é a parte importante do código.

Eu já vi código com 200 mil linhas que eu faria em 10 mil. Sem exagero. Por causa das técnicas de **bom *design*** adotados. Qual código você acha que é mais fácil dar manutenção?

Bem, claro, é a técnica sendo mal usada, mas quem não consegue programar direito só vai se complicar mais com técnicas mais complexas.

Para fazer TDD exige um *design* específico cheio de camadas. Nem sempre você precisa dessas camadas para resolver o problema que tem na mão. É o desenvolvedor trabalhando para o seu próprio problema e não para o problema que ele precisa resolver.

Eu não tenho duvida que o TDD obriga o desenvolvedor fazer o *design* que algumas pessoas gostam. Daí dizer que isso é bom *design* precisa de provas. Opinião todo mundo pode ter. Tanto que eu apenas acho que o TDD não é uma solução, mas não tenho certeza.

## Desenvolver a necessidade antes da solução é antigo

Na verdade já se fazia uma forma semelhante há muito tempo e se chamava programação *top-down*, que era o oposto de *bottom-up*. A primeira técnica vai fazendo o que precisa em nível mais alto e vai desenvolvendo o que é necessário para cumprir isso, que é uma forma muito parecida com TDD. Mas criando uma técnica nova daria pra vender consultoria, palestras, livros, cursos, etc. Se precisa vender tanto assim, tenho dúvidas se é bom. O que é bom de verdade as pessoas adotam fácil.

Claro que TDD exige muito mais coisas.

## Agile

Pra falar a verdade TDD é ferramenta importante em Agile. Essa metodologia prega que você não deve planejar muito, que tudo deve ser fácil de refazer. Eu sou um pouco crítico de Agile. A ideia é boa. Mas não vejo bons resultados.

Todo mundo sabe que o desenvolvimento é a parte fácil, difícil é dar manutenção, inclusive porque será feita muita manutenção e pouco desenvolvimento inicial.

Quando você começa colocar muito penduricalho para facilitar a manutenção pode acabar complicando ela. Quando você tenta fazer rápido o que vai consumir 5%, 1%, quem sabe menos que isso, e cria dificultadores para o resto do trabalho, me parece algo contraproducente.

De fato tenho observado projetos *open* que adotam Agile, e alguns até que passaram usar Agile em determinado momento podendo comparar com os resultados quando não eram Agile. Só projetos *high profile*. Eu vejo uma diminuição na produtividade do projeto conforme o tempo passa. E não vi tanto, antes de se tornar Agile. Um dos motivos que antes era mais produtivo é que o *design* era mais planejado antes.

Muitos desses projetos começam a negar colocar certos recursos porque não encaixam no *design* iniciado, e mudar isso complica demais. O produto começa a sofrer.

É muito comum projetos serem feitos por Agile e depois fica pra outra equipe dar manutenção que no fim não conseguem dar continuidade nele e acabam fazendo outro.

Cada vez mais vemos novos projetos concorrentes entre si ou que servem para matar um existente porque a engenharia inicial estava errada. A reescrita é a única saída, o que muita gente diz que é a última coisa que você deveria fazer.

Nesse ponto eu até gosto de Agile, já que eu sou um que acha que todo software tem um tempo de vida útil. Pode até ser que mude daqui pra frente porque a computação e a engenharia de software talvez tenha alcançado uma boa maturidade, mas até agora softwares com 3 décadas, mesmo que muito bem desenvolvidos, carregam muito legado e ficam com manutenção impraticável.

Começar desenvolver algo é fácil, manter é complicado. TDD não ajuda mais que fazer testes de unidade que ajudam sim o desenvolvedor mudar com confiança.

Isto prova alguma coisa? Não. É só minha experiência.

Não estou dizendo que Agile é ruim e que nunca deva ser usado. Só que tenho visto os projetos se arrastarem cada vez mais e em determinado momento eles começam de novo porque chegou em um ponto que a manutenção ficou insustentável. Essa é uma verdade que é jogada em baixo do tapete.

Olhe que eu já comprei a ideia de Agile antes. Não fechei os olhos para ela, não. Também não sou aquele cara que cria uma pilha de documentos que especificam o software. É um meio termo. Pra falar a verdade nem me parece que o TDD tem cara de Agile já que ele exige documentar demais.

## Conclusão

Pode ser que algumas pessoas só consigam pensar no problema fazendo TDD. Ok. É uma forma. Mas não é o TDD que fez o *design* ficar bom.

Tudo o que eu disse aqui tem a mesma credibilidade que os proponentes de TDD. Muito pouca. Então você tem que achar o que é bom para você. E de preferência isso deve ser feito de acordo com cada projeto. Respeito quem discorda, mas novamente, se a pessoa quiser que eu adote me apresente provas cabais que é uma melhoria. Eu quero ter certeza que ele é bom.

Tem uma resposta sobre isto aqui: [Como efetuar TDD na camada Service](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19020/101).

Mais [um complemento](http://ravimohan.blogspot.com.br/2007/04/learning-from-sudoku-solvers.html).

Não deixe de ler *link* da pergunta e a duplicata marcada lá.

Frase-chave:

> How do you know what you don’t know?  -- Peter Novig

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu trabalho numa empresa com 14 desenvolvedores. Trabalhamos ano após ano no mesmo produto, adicionando funcionalidades e melhorando UI e performance. Nosso maior custo é código ruim. Pior ainda, um cara programar algo que não dá certo nem mesmo no happy day. Eu sou defensor que apliquem TDD para que haja uma garantia mínima de que o código funcione, de que o antigo estava errado (caso seja uma correção) e também como forma de, na revisão/auditoria de código, possa-se ensinar ao programador junior algo a mais sobre orientação a objeto, ou acoplamento, ou complexidade/performance de algoritmo

Comment: Nesse caso em específico, de um produto de software altamente sofisticado, mantido por uma equipe não muito pequena, um software que demanda manutenção longa, creio que o TDD seja vantajoso