# Os teste Unitários estão corretos?

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Estou participando de um processo seletivo, e um dos critérios é implementar qualquer tipo de teste unitários, eu só gostaria de saber se está implementado certo o código abaixo, ele está funcionando perfeitamente, só preciso saber se está implementado certo.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TesteApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private PessoaRepository pessoaRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PessoaService pessoaService;

    @Test
    public void testPessoa1Inclusao() throws Exception {
        Pessoa pessoa1 = new Pessoa("Marcelo Dultra", "840.622.210-71");
        this.pessoaService.salvar(pessoa1);
        // Assertions.assertThat(pessoa1.getName()).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPessoa2Exclusao() throws Exception {

        Pessoa pessoa = pessoaRepository.findOne((long) 3);
        pessoaRepository.delete(pessoa);    
    }

    @Test
    public void testPessoa3ExclusaoDaUltima() throws Exception {
        List<Pessoa> todasPessoas = pessoaRepository.findAll();
        Pessoa ultima = todasPessoas.get(todasPessoas.size() - 1);
        pessoaRepository.delete(ultima);    
    }

    @Test
    public void testPessoa4Atualizacao() throws Exception {
        Pessoa pessoa3 = new Pessoa("Ricardo Falcão1", "213.535.690-55");
        this.pessoaService.atualizar(pessoa3.getCodigo().valueOf(4), pessoa3);

    }



}
```

Comment: Como vamos saber? Não sabemos os requisitos. Não conhecemos profundamente o problema. Fazer teste é entender o problema. Olhando o código por cima parece que nem o código real parece estar certo (sem vê-lo). Quando tem algo conceitualmente errado de que adianta testar? E mesmo olhando só os testes, eles são ingênuos, está tentando ver se faz algo em uma situação específica demais, que é pra dar certo sempre. Teste é muito mais complicado e quase odo mundo faz só pra se sentir bem e estar na moda, não para fazer a aplicação ficar robusta de verdade, então é desperdício de tempo.

Comment: Maneiro eu não concordo, partindo do pressuposto que uma das melhores empresas do Brasil solicitou os teste unitários como parte do processo seletivo, se as empresas solicitam é porque é importante, mas isso não é um fórum de discussão, eu ficaria muito contente se pudesse dar uma resposta mais amigável.

Comment: Maneiro, tem um cara que se diz professor de algoritmo, e ele disse que meus testes estão errados, porque teste unitários não são para efetivar CRUD no banco, como tenho pouca experiência não sei afirma se ele está errado. Será que estes testes unitários que fiz estão realmente errados?

Comment: Fiz um comentário amigável, mas você está pedindo para ouvir o que você quer, isso eu não faço porque isso é enganação, como você foi enganado por " uma das melhores empresas do Brasil solicitou os teste unitários como parte do processo seletivo". E "um cara que se diz professor de algoritmo" que maravilha de credencial. Mas ele está certo, só que não é o único problema. Sinto muito não poder ajudar mais, e você não querer a ajuda que eu posso dar.

Comment: @wladyband realmente o cara que se diz professor está certo. Os testes unitários são para testar regras de negócio. Por exemplo, se o cadastro é de pessoa e possui CPF, o sistema deve validar se o CPF/CNPJ é válido, se a data de nascimento não é maior que 150 anos por exemplo. Que são validações que o banco de dados por si só não faça. Não sou grande conhecedora de testes, mas já trabalhei com TDD. Faça sempre testes de falha e acerto, em que passe no teste se falhar e passe no teste se acertar. Mais aqui: https://www.devmedia.com.br/tdd-fundamentos-do-desenvolvimento-orientado-a-testes/28151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseada no meu comentário a sua pergunta, além de reafirmar que os testes unitários são para testes a regra de negócio e devem ter testes tanto de erro quanto de acerto, é bacana colocar que os testes unitários devem testar uma parte pequena da regra de negócio.

Minha sugestão é que você crie uma classe validadora de pessoas. Essa classe terá método de validação de CPF/CNPJ, de Inscrição Estadual, de data de nascimento, de e-mail, de telefone, da já existência do CPF/CNPJ inserido e etc. Depende de quão rico você queira suas validações. No caso da exclusão, você pode colocar validações de vinculações da pessoa excluída com outras entidades de pessoa como endereços (1 - n), caso a exclusão não seja lógica. O que causaria problemas no banco de dados com a `foreign key`.

Tente sempre fazer um teste que o valor inserido passe e um teste que o valor inserido não passe (ou seja, o acerto é vir erro). Adicione a sua classe de validadores mensagens amigáveis que sugiram ao usuário como o mesmo deve corrigir o erro e não simplesmente dizendo que está errado.

Mais materiais, caso queira ler sobre o assunto:

"[Entenda de uma vez por todas o que são testes unitários](https://medium.com/@dayvsonlima/entenda-de-uma-vez-por-todas-o-que-s%C3%A3o-testes-unit%C3%A1rios-para-que-servem-e-como-faz%C3%AA-los-2a6f645bab3)"

"[Teste de Software](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_software)"

"[TDD fundamentos do desenvolvimento orientado a testes](https://www.devmedia.com.br/tdd-fundamentos-do-desenvolvimento-orientado-a-testes/28151)"

"[E ai? Como você testa seus códigos?](https://www.devmedia.com.br/e-ai-como-voce-testa-seus-codigos/39478)"

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que observei, o que você fez foram **testes de integração** e não testes unitários.

Testes unitários abrangem uma pequena parte do código, são simples e testam lógicas internas da aplicação comumente relacionados ao negócio envolvido, indo das regras mais simples (se o campo está no formato correto, se o limite de caracteres está correto, etc) até os mais complexas (se o usuário está bloqueado, se o usuário pode fazer uma compra dado o crédito dele, etc).

Estes testes que abrangem várias camadas são comumente conhecidos como testes de integração, que é o caso do código que fez. O código está fazendo consultas a um banco de dados (um H2 em memória, presumo). O código aparentemente também não está testando qualquer lógica criada por você. Também não estou vendo nenhum `assert` de resultado (o único do código está comentado), para assegurar que o comportamento esperado foi alcançado.

Um exemplo de teste unitário, no conceito que você apresentou, poderia ser validar o CPF da pessoa, retornando uma exception `CpfInvalidoException` caso seja inválido:

```
class PessoaTest {

    @Test(expects = CpfInvalidoException.class);
    public void naoSalvarPessoaComCpfInvalido() {
        PessoaService pessoaService = new PessoaService(mock(PessoaRepository.class));
        pessoaService.salvar(new Pessoa("Marcelo Dultra", "840.622.210"));
    }

}
```